# Passing the object using GoToAsync Dictionary ends up with receiving Null .net 7 Maui

Tags: c#, xamarin, maui

The problem is that using GoToAsync combined with Dictionary ends up with receiving null object on the page I'm navigating to. I'm just stuck...

What is interesting and maybe a good hint.
I have a breakpoint on my GoToAsync, and at the execution time my object contain data I need.
Next breakpoint is on my constructor on page I'm navigating to, after that breakpoint my object become null.

The routing is correctly set.

**GoToAsync**:

```
private async void ListView_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
        {
            var salons = e.Item as Salons;
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("TemplateSalonPage", true, new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                {"Salons", salons }
            });
```

The **Viewmodel** of my navigation to page:

```
ing xxx.Models;
using xxx.Views;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace xxx.ViewModels;

[QueryProperty(nameof(Salons), "Salons")]
public partial class TemplateSalonViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public TemplateSalonViewModel()
    {
        
    }

[ObservableProperty]
Salons salon;

}
```

View **.xaml** of receiver:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="xxx.Views.TemplateSalonPage"
xmlns:model="clr-namespace:xxx.Models"
xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:xxx.ViewModels"
x:DataType="viewModels:TemplateSalonViewModel"           Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False"        Shell.TabBarIsVisible="False">

<StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
<VerticalStackLayout>
            <Label Text="{Binding Salon.id}"
                               FontSize="Large"
                               FontAttributes="Bold" 
                               VerticalOptions="Center"
                               BackgroundColor="Yellow"
                               TextColor="Black"
                                   HeightRequest="150"/>
        </VerticalStackLayout>
</StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Tried with any possible variations of naming my objects, dictionary but couldn't find an issue. Binding works because I am able to attach it in the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misunderstand the `[QueryProperty(nameof(Salons), "Salons")]`. In you code, the property name is **salon**. And because you used the `[ObservableProperty]`, the **salon** will be declare as **Salon**.

So the viewmodel should be:

```
[QueryProperty(nameof(Salon), "Salons")]
public partial class TemplateSalonViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public TemplateSalonViewModel()
    {
        
    }

[ObservableProperty]
Salons salon;

}
```

And in the xaml, you also need to use the `Salon.Id`. Sich as:

```
<Label Text="{Binding Salon.Id}"
```

For more information, you can refer to the official document about the [ObservableProperty attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/generators/errors/mvvmtk0034).

**And I have created a sample with the CommunityToolkit.Mvvm nuget package:**

The ViewModel:

```
    [QueryProperty(nameof(Persiontest),"Person")]
    public partial class ViewModelTest : ObservableObject
    {
        [ObservableProperty]
        Person persiontest;
    }
```

The Model class:

```
public partial class Person : ObservableObject
    {
        [ObservableProperty]
        public string name;
        [ObservableProperty]
        public int id;
    }
```

And use the Shell.Current.Goto():

```
var persons = new Person() { Id = 1,Name="AAAAAA" };
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("NewPage1", true, new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "Person", persons }}) ;
```

And the Page.xaml:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local ="clr-namespace:Testinherit"
             x:Class="Testinherit.NewPage1"
             Title="NewPage1">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <local:ViewModelTest/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label x:Name="label" Text="{Binding Persiontest.Name}"/>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: The solution was to set the [ObservableP..ty]  naming properly as you just said. What a relief